# Register hotkeys in Linux using library for c++

Tags: c++, linux, hotkeys

are there any libraries for Linux wrote with C++, that could register global hotkeys for my application? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll have to provide more information.

In Gnome, the global functionality varies by window manager.  Metacity has configurable  global shortcuts, as do Compiz and Sawfish, and they're all configured differently.  [Xhotkeys](http://www.nongnu.org/xhotkeys/) can also be used for the same functionality.  However, these are all limited to starting applications only.

Within the KDE application framework, [KAction](http://api.kde.org/4.x-api/kdelibs-apidocs/kdeui/html/classKAction.html) can register global shortcuts which perform actions inside your program.  These are actually handled by a module in kded (launched on demand), so they work even outside of the KDE desktop environment.

If you don't use the KDE framework, but are still using X11, you can use the xlib API to call [XGrabKey](http://www.xfree.org/current/XGrabKey.3.html) on the root window.

For shortcuts that work outside of X, as long as you are running as root (or permissions are changed permissively) on a 2.6 kernel, you can directly open [`/dev/input/event*`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/input.txt), and poll for the desired key events.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a simple C library a while back to make registering global X11 hotkeys a little less painful. There are some examples with the code. You can get it at:

https://github.com/jwmcode/xhklib/

Comment: xhklib used the XGrabKey(), it will generate focusout, do you know any function without generating focusout? Look at:http://stackoverflow.com/q/15270420/264181